# Ember Rails route URLS based on json ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, model, routes

This seems like it should be pretty simple but I can't seem to figure this out (bit new to Ember). I have a json file that I am using to load data into an ember template with handlebars. I am trying to have it so by visiting /site/id/ it would load data based on the id in the json file. Right now, it loads my json but only takes data from the first json entry. So no matter what /site/anythinghere/, that data is loaded. I am trying to make it dynamic.

I think my problem has to do with not having a model setup properly in ember. I've seen the docs and tutorials talk about the model: property and passing (params) and what not, but I can't seem to get anything to work in my site model or route.

Here's my code...

Router.js.coffee:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'site', ->
    @route 'show', path: '/:site_id'
```

Routes.rb:

```
#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: 'home#index'

scope constraints: { format: :html } do
   get '/site' => 'home#index'
   get '/site/:site_id' => 'home#index'
   resources 'sites'
  end
end
```

sites_controller.rb:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: File.open('data/sites.json').read
  end
end
```

models/site.js.coffee:

```
App.Site = DS.Model.extend()
```

data/sites.json

```
{
    "site": [

        {

        "id": "1",
        "name": "Place One",
        "type": "Type One"

        }, {

        "id": "2",
        "name": "Place One",
        "type": "Type Two"

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are your routes set up properly? It seems like you want /site/id to route to your show action on the sites controller but you're routing it to home#index

Comment: Yeah I'm routing my rails to my ember outlet, thats why they all go to the same place. Ember handles the routing.